# A bounded set in the collection of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be a collection of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{F\in A} F=\emptyset$. If some element of $A$ is bounded, then there exist $F_1,F_2,...,F_n\in A$ where $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}F_k=\emptyset$.

I tried to solve this problem but I only achieve particular cases, where I can begin here?

Comment: You may call this problem as Cantor's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some element $X\in A$ is bounded, then as it is also closed, $X$ will be compact.  Also $X$ will be covered by the complements of the remaining elements of $A$ (as the intersection of the elements of $A$ is empty).  Thus $X$ will be covered by a finite subset $X_1^c,\cdots X_n^c$ of the complements of elements of $A$.  Thus the intersection of $X$ and the $X_i$ is empty.